# Playing sound notification with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, notifications, playback

im using this function to get notification. What i need is when i have new notification to play a notification sound.

```
function load_unseen_notification(view = '')
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"fetch-notification.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{view:view},
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('.dropdown-menu').html(data.notification);
        if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
        {
         $('.count').html(data.unseen_notification);
         var audio = new Audio('http://localhost/ios_notification.mp3')
         audio.play()
     
        }
       }
      });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var audio = new Audio('http://localhost/ios_notification.mp3')
```

in this line you are trying to call the constructor function of `Audio(url)`. Do you have a server running on `http://localhost:80`? `80` is the default port for `http`. + it is not possible without `html5`, the return value of the `Audio` constructor is `HTMLAudioElement`.

Comment: yes the server is running on 80 and running on localhost

Comment: could you double check whether the resource (`'http://localhost/ios_notification.mp3'`) actually exists and served while the server is running?